# Extra reload animations in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

Sometimes, when I reload a weapon, an extra animation occurs.  For example, when reloading the Chinese Assault Rifle, occassionally the player will pull out the magazine, tap it against the side of the gun, and put it back in the gun.

What is with these extra reload animations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, this means the condition of your gun is low and needs to be reapired.

From the wiki:

> Another consequence of poor condition when using weapons is the reload animation. The lower the condition of a weapon, the more likely it is to jam, causing the player to adjust the magazine, thus taking longer to complete the animation. A weapon at 100% condition will never jam, while weapons in a poor state of repair will jam quite frequently.

So in short, repair that gun and no more extra animation.

Source: [Fallout Wiki: Condition](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Condition)

Comment: Sounds about right. I was quite obsessive about keeping my weapons in good condition and didn't notice any jams.